# Wordpress - reference JS-file without '?ver=4.6'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

in my WP-Plugin I do enqueue my JS file

```
wp_enqueue_script('myjs', $pluginpath . 'build/js/app.min.js', array('jquery'));
```

so WP gererates the site-header:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/build/js/app.min.js?ver=4.6'></script>
```

this `?ver=4.6` causes, that when I make changes to the app.min.js, those aren't loaded.. instead a cached version of the `app.min.js' seems to be loaded

how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

`$ver`:

(string|bool|null) (Optional) String specifying script version number, if it has one, which is added to the URL as a query string for cache busting purposes. If version is set to false, a version number is automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version. **If set to null, no version is added.**

Default value: false
So you should use this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('myjs', $pluginpath . 'build/js/app.min.js', array('jquery'), null);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you :) .. but that somehow doesn't work. I have already tried this and WP still puts the Version behind the JS .. I have also tried to write 'NULL' and 'null' which seems dumb but I really don't know what else to try

Comment: @crunchy Did you clean all caches?

Comment: I am looking after a option to do that, but there is no menu-entry for cache.. i have no caching-plugin installed.. do i need a plugin to cear some internal WP-cache?

Comment: @crunchy Are you testing it on localhost?

Comment: Your browser will include developer tools. In chrome for example you can open the dev tools and in the settings there is an option "disable browser cache while devtools are open" firefox et al will have the same option.

Comment: @Pk19000  no, on remote-server

Comment: @crunchy It's maybe because of server cache or router cache!  (I say this because I had a problem as like as this!!) Can you check it in localhost?

Comment: oh my .. sorry guys.. i'm sooo stupid :/ .. maybe I should take a nap :D .. have looked into the sourcecode of my plugin at a point at which i do parse a whole html-template instead of letting WP render its own .. so the `null`-answer is correct and works :) .. thank you all! :)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). The default value of `$ver` is false, which sets the query string to the WP version you are using. Use `null` to turn it off:

```
// Do not inject query string
wp_enqueue_script('myjs', $pluginpath . 'build/js/app.min.js', array('jquery'), null);
```

…or specify a version explicitly, say, '1.2.3':

```
// Use custom query string
wp_enqueue_script('myjs', $pluginpath . 'build/js/app.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.2.3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) it indicates that you can pass the value `null` for the version. This will override default behaviour and remove the query string.

```
wp_enqueue_script('myjs', $pluginpath . 'build/js/app.min.js', array('jquery'), null);
```

Comment: Hi, that somehow doesn't work.. I have already tried with `null` and `NULL`

Comment: Hey, how are you checking the version which is being loaded?

Comment: I look directly in the sourcecode of the rendered page

Comment: You could try cachebusting by generating a random number and putting that into the version instead of `null`

Comment: I have tried that already, too :/ .. still the `?ver=4.6` there

Comment: Have you looked at this article? https://wordimpress.com/wordpress-css-and-js-cache-busting/